# which WSDL tags can have documentation tag?

Tags: wsdl

am trying to do WSDL parsing (using c#.net) with some statisics on it. my statisics depends on documentation tags in WSDL. i want to know list of wsdl tags that can contains documentation tag to check on them.

i tried to read the WS-I basic profile and i found :

---

5.1.10 WSDL documentation Element

The WSDL 1.1 schema and the WSDL 1.1 specification are inconsistent with respect to where wsdl:documentation elements may be placed.

R2020 The wsdl:documentation element MAY occur as a child of the wsdl:import element in a DESCRIPTION. WSDL20

R2021 The wsdl:documentation element MAY occur as a child of the wsdl:part element in a DESCRIPTION. WSDL20

R2024 The wsdl:documentation element MAY occur as a first child of the wsdl:definitions element in a DESCRIPTION. WSDL20

---

however, this profile is made in 2004 so did they apply changes? can a documentation tag be a part of any inner child-tag of the current tag?

Thank you 
Kawthar almatori

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the [WS-I basic profile 2.0](http://ws-i.org/profiles/basicprofile-2.0-2010-11-09.html) states, there are some inconsistencies between the [WSDL 1.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl) and the [WSDL 1.1 schema](http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/). According to the schema a `<wsdl:documentation>` element is allowed as the *first* child of the following elements:

```
/definitions
/definitions/binding
/definitions/binding/operation
/definitions/binding/operation/fault
/definitions/binding/operation/input
/definitions/binding/operation/output
/definitions/import
/definitions/message
/definitions/message/part
/definitions/portType
/definitions/portType/operation
/definitions/portType/operation/fault
/definitions/portType/operation/input
/definitions/portType/operation/output
/definitions/service
/definitions/service/port
/definitions/types
```

The WSDL 1.1 specification differs in the following ways:

- It places the `/definitions/documentation` element after the `/definitions/import` element(s), if present.
- It does not allow `<wsdl:documentation>` children on the `/definitions/import` or `/definitions/message/part` elements.

The statements in the WS-I basic profile basically reaffirm the WSDL 1.1 schema, allowing  on the `/definitions/import` and `/definitions/message/part` elements, and specifying that `<wsdl:documentation>` is allowed as the *first* child of `/definitions`