# Reliably parse documentation tag from any WSDL

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl, simplexml

I need to parse an XML file so I always find the  element,  [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042652/which-wsdl-tags-can-have-documentation-tag) this element can be the first child element of many other elements so there is no easy way to parse it. Currently, I am parsing it only from this WSDL.

```
<portType name="ndfdXMLPortType">
<operation name="NDFDgen">
<documentation>My Documentation... lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</documentation>
<input message="tns:NDFDgenRequest" />
<output message="tns:NDFDgenResponse" />
</operation>
</portType>
```

Using this code

```
  $documentations = $styles = $outputs = array();
  if (!empty($array)) {
    foreach ($array['portType']['operation'] as $operation) {
      $documentations[$operation['@attributes']['name']] = $operation['documentation'];
    }
    foreach ($array['binding']['operation'] as $key => $operation) {
      $styles[$operation['@attributes']['name']] = $operation['operation']['@attributes']['style'];
      $outputs[$operation['@attributes']['name']] = $xml->binding->operation[$key]->output->body->asXML();
    }
  }
```

But I need to parse it from *any* WSDL file. For example, in a different WSDL it shows up like.

```
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="BillingPeriod" type="ebl:BillingPeriodType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation> Installment Period.
<br />
<b>Optional</b>
<br />
</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this looks like two different elements. The first `documentation` would be in the WSDL namespace (`http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/`). Your second example, seems to be schema(`http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`).

Your examples miss the namespace definitions. Look for `xmlns` and `xmlns:xs` attributes. The following 3 examples can all be read as `{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}documentation`.

- `<documentation xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"/>`
- `<wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"/>`
- `<w:documentation xmlns:w="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"/>`

An XML parser will resolve namespace definitions. You can have the same local name for a node. Depending on the prefixes and namespace definitions they might represent different things.

You seem to use SimpleXML and convert it to an array. Don't do that conversion. SimpleXML allows you to use PHP syntax to access XML, already. But the SimpleXMLElement objects still have methods to make access easier. You will loose that and information if you convert its debug output to an array.

SimpleXMLElement allows you to use Xpath to fetch nodes:

```
$element = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
// register your own prefixes for the namespaces
$element->registerXPathNamespace('xsd', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema');
$element->registerXpathNamespace('wsdl', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/');

// fetch the documentation elements from both namespaces
$expression = '//xsd:documentation|//wsdl:documentation';
var_dump(
    (string)$element->xpath($expression)[0]
);
```

Or in DOM:

```
$document = new \DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new \DOMXpath($document);
// register your own prefixes for the namespaces
$xpath->registerNamespace('xsd', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema');
$xpath->registerNamespace('wsdl', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/');

// fetch the documentation elements from both namespaces and 
// cast the first into a string
$expression = 'string(//xsd:documentation|//wsdl:documentation)';
var_dump(
    $xpath->evaluate($expression)
);
```

Comment: Actually they are both parsed as "description" https://services.w3.org/xslt?xslfile=http://tomi.vanek.sk/xml/wsdl-viewer.xsl&amp;xmlfile=https://graphical.weather.gov/xml/DWMLgen/wsdl/ndfdXML.wsdl&amp;transform=Submit  https://services.w3.org/xslt?xslfile=http://tomi.vanek.sk/xml/wsdl-viewer.xsl&amp;xmlfile=http://webservices.flightexplorer.com/FastTrack.asmx?wsdl&amp;transform=Submit

Comment: The both have the local name `description`, but they can be in different namespaces. In the wsdl files you linked they are in `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/` namespace. I will change my answer.

Comment: They both get parsed by WSDL viewer as "description" on the operation. So wondering how I can do the same.

Comment: Use Xpath expressions like in my code examples. It allows you to fetch nodes/values using location paths and conditions.